# Meaning of "$[G:G_a]$"?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> When we write "$[G:G_a]$", what does it really mean? Which concept does it point to? How is it pronounced?

Comment: Please format the mathematical expressions using MathJax so that it is easier to read.

Comment: Where can I find MatJax? What is it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_a_subgroup

Answer (score 1):

It's likely the index of a subgroup in a group.

Comment: Is Index same as Cardinality ?

Comment: @RuhiKhan, it's the cardinality of $G/G_a$, which is the set of residue classes of $G_a$ in $G$, irrespective of whether or not $G_a$ is normal.